# Report on which users have granted login access to Administrator

Tags: force.com, user, user-management, workbench

I know how to grant login access to administrator/salesforce. What I want to know is in which object is this setting stored? I want to do reporting on all the users in my org who have granted access to administrators

Is this setting stored in any object which I can access from workbench?

Comment: you can configure the org so that all users have implicitly granted access to the administrator. This is super convenient at reproducing user issues

Comment: Because of some requirements, I can't enable that setting in my org. At the same time I would like to generate a report of how many users have granted login access to admins. Which object stores this setting?